# VS 2010 - TFS Restrict Checking without Attaching Task , BUG

Tags: tfs, checkin

We are using VS 2010 and using TFS for Checkin code.
I want all developer to attach Task , BUG with code when they do checkin.
What is the policy i need to apply to get this done.

Thanks.
Dev

Answer (score 7):

Right click on your Team Project in Team Explorer and choose "Team Project Settings" > "Source Control...". Then click on the "Check-in Policy" tab.

From there you can "Add..." a policy requiring a Work Item.

[image: Source Control Settings]

Comment: This answer only explains how to require a work item.  OP asked about requiring specific work item types.

Comment: I don't think that is available out of the box